Postgresql Error when deploying with Netlify
I am Getting the following error codes when trying to deploy a rails/react webapp on netlify. I've ran brew install libpq and pkg-config, gem installed pg 1.5.6 but the same errors remain.

9:47:32 PM: Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
9:47:32 PM: Unable to find PostgreSQL client library.
An error occurred while installing pg (1.5.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
In Gemfile:
pg
Error during gem install
9:47:32 PM: Failing build: Failed to install dependencies
9:47:32 PM: Finished processing build request in 33.864s

